# How to represent in xy axys element position given distance between three points?

Tags: math, location, position, trigonometry, triangulation

I got two antennas separated by one meter receiving signal from a device. I'm measuring distance from antennas to device based in signal strength. I would like to convert metrics space references [(1,3,5),(1,4,6),(1,7,5)]on xy values ((-2,4),(1,5),(2.3)), like a device relative position reference.

What would be the basic approach for this calculation?

Edit:
Two range multilateration like comments say seems a good first approach

```py
r_2_1 = pow(antenna[0], 2) + pow(antenna[1], 2)
r_2_2 = pow((0.15-antenna[0]), 2) + pow(antenna[1], 2)

x_coordinate = (r_2_1 - r_2_2 + pow(0.15, 2)) / ((0.15)*2)
y_coordinate = math.sqrt(pow(r_2_1, 2) - pow(x_coordinate, 2))
```

I'm trying to represent in a x,y axis the distance from a device to two diferent antennas (0.15 is separation between antennas, antenna is the couple of distances).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what exactly you're asking but it sounds like you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_range_multilateration#Two_Cartesian_dimensions,_two_measured_slant_ranges_(Trilateration) Can you edit the question to clarify, for example give an example of the input and output, **and also** tell us what programming tools you are using (language, framework) - pure math questions are off-topic on this site